# Cartopy projection transformations - transforming from integer values to map coordinates

Tags: python, cartopy

I have a 2d image along with its projection information.

I can't figure out how to transform from pixel numbers into the correct projection.

For example

```
In [23]: image.shape
Out[23]: (1351, 1143)

In [24]: projection
Out[24]: _EPSGProjection(32611)
```

I want to now plot a circle at indices (500, 700) with radius 10

I think I can do something like this to get the point in the correct projection:

```
projection.transform_point(500, 700, ???)
```

but I don't know what the pixel-based coordinate reference system should be.

Am I completely missing something obvious with projections?

Here's a basic example:

```
image=np.random.rand(500, 500)

crs_latlon = ccrs.PlateCarree()

subplot_kw = dict(projection=crs_latlon)

fig, ax= plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 10), subplot_kw=subplot_kw)

ax.imshow(image, extent=(-20, 20, -15, 15))
ax.set_extent((-30, 30, -25, 25))

ax.coastlines()
plt.show()
```

This plots an image of random data over the coast of Africa.

How do I now reference something at the index of the original image?

e.g. Draw a circle centred on image(200, 400)?

Comment: The image's extent (first column, last column, bottom row, top row), maps to the extent (left, right, bottom, top) or (-20, 20, -15, 15) degrees on the map.
That's the coordinate conversion part.

Comment: For a circle plot, you have to decide:- a real circle patch or a Tissot's indicatrix.